# Android: database getInt()

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void insert(View target){
    String mBirth = birth_year.getText().toString();
    String mName = name.getText().toString();
    String mHome = hometown.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mBirth+mName+mHome ,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO member VALUES (null, '"+ mBirth + "', '"
            + mName + "', '" + mHome + "');");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "saved.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    birth_year.setText("");
    name.setText("");
    hometown.setText("");
}

public void search(View target){
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT b_year, b_name, b_city FROM member;",null);
    String mBirth="Year\n", mName="Name\n", mHome="City\n";
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        int gBirth = cursor.getInt(0);
        String gName = cursor.getString(1);
        String gHome = cursor.getString(2);
        mBirth += (Integer.toString(gBirth)+'\n');
        mName += (gName+'\n');
        mHome += (gHome+'\n');
    }
    btext.setText(mBirth);
    ntext.setText(mName);
    htext .setText(mHome);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mBirth+mName+mHome ,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I have a problem that database doesn't work as I expected. 
When I execute `insert()`, it doesn't write anything on `birth_year` what is `Edit_Text`, I expect that `db.execSQL()` will throw `SQLiteException`.
But Exception is not thrown, and when I execute `search()`, `gBirth` is `0` . [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orpcL.png) 
The result is shown in the link. I want to throw exception when I execute `insert()` which doesn't write anything on `birth_year`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Add your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[execSQL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) only throws an exception if the SQL string is invalid. Change it for an [insert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) and if it returns `-1` throw your own exception or just use [insertOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues))